# SQL file importing doesn't work while using command line

Tags: mysql

I have a large `.sql`. file and I'm trying to import it by using command line. Im going to the right directory and typing:

```
mysql -u rookie -h 127.0.0.1 -p database < file.sql
```

And somehow it gives me an error:

```
Mysql is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Why?

Comment: just a tip - if -h = localhost you don't need to specify it :)

Answer (score 1):

Linux can't find the binary `mysql`.

**Quick fix:**

Check the location of the `mysql` binary with the following command: `which mysql`.

You will then see output similar to the following:
`/usr/bin/mysql`

Rewrite your command as:

`/usr/bin/mysql -u rookie -h 127.0.0.1 -p database < file.sql`

**Longterm solution:**

Add `mysql` to your `$PATH` environment variable like so:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/mysql` (of course put your own `mysql` path at the end here.)

Comment: +1 another solution worth adding - if you run mysql in terminal you can use `source path/to.file.sql` to import a file

Comment: Why when I'm writing `which mysql` it says that `which is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I'm writing the command into my project root directory. Is it ok?

Comment: You should check your `.bashrc` file to see how the `$PATH` variable is set there. The file can be found in your home directory.

Comment: I've tried to search `bashrc` or `.bashrc` over the whole xampp directory, but it didn't found any results..

Comment: @user7435747 that's because PdC is suggesting a solution for Linux - `which` isn't a Windows command. And `.bashrc` doesn't live in XAMPP - it lives in your ~ directory